# right to left multi-column in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

in crystal report we can implementing left to right multi-column by default but i need change direction of multi-column report to RTL, is there any solution for that?

many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible using standard functionality- but how about this for a workaround:

Let us imagine we currently have a single detail row a.

- Create a new detail row b.
- Move the fields on detail row a to the right hand side.
- Copy the fields to detail row b on the left hand side.
- Set detail section a to underlay following sections.
- Set detail section a to suppress conditionally with: `recordnumber mod 2 = 1`
- Set detail section b to suppress conditionally with: `recordnumber mod 2 = 0`

Voila?

Comment: i have used this approach too but i need to know better than this. however many thanks.

Comment: i think there is a standard solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can Using "Format Object".

1. Right Click on object what You want
2. Format Object
3. Click On Tab "Paragraph"
4. Choose "Right To Left" From Frame "Reading Oder"
5. Choose "RTF Text" from Frame "Text InterPretation"

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. My requirement was to display Arabic text Right-to-left in two columns of a report. To achieve what I wanted I used the below formula for each and every fields in the report:

```
IF ONFIRSTRECORD THEN 
    NEXT({FIELDNAME})
ELSE IF recordnumber mod 2 = 1 THEN ` NEXT({FIELDNAME})`

ELSE
    PREVIOUS({FIELDNAME})
```

HOPE THIS HELPS :)