# RDLC Matrix (Tablix) grow to right side even after set LayoutDirection RTL

Tags: c#, report, rdlc, reportviewer

I export RDLC reports to PDF using the ReportViewer and I need to print the report  data from right to left , All reports contain a Matrix (Tablix) or table and I set Layout Direction property RTL for all  Matrix (Tablix) and Table and it reflect the columns order from right to left, but the matrix/table itself grow to right side (from left to right).

I tried to change report language but is doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 1):

I think this a duplicate of this post [How to make the tablix in .rdlc reports start from the right and expand to the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54409292/how-to-make-the-tablix-in-rdlc-reports-start-from-the-right-and-expand-to-the-l)

I'm afraid this is not possible, because the problem is not the **content** (which the RTL properties affects) of the tablix, but the **alignment**

Unfortunately, there is no property in RDLC to let you control this smoothly.
But if you use third-party plugins like [Telerik](https://www.telerik.com/forums/right-to-left-problem-in-grid), you can achieve the desired result.

Comment: thanks @Sweet I try crystal report and I have the same issue , Is there any solution to create this pdf with a correct alignment

Comment: ok. After googling a bit, i came across some useful links, may be that can help you. [From SAP](https://answers.sap.com/questions/10221102/how-to-draw-cross-tab-crystal-report-from-right-to.html), [From SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658694/right-to-left-multi-column-in-crystal-report)